# How to auto increment the primary key?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this sql query to create my `Penguin` table

```
CREATE TABLE Penguin (
PenguinID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(10),
Height FLOAT,
Weight FLOAT)
```

But then when I do `INSERT INTO Penguin (Name, Height, Weight) VALUES (?,?,?)` only the name, height and weight are added, and the `PenguinID` column is NULL

Comment: `PenguinID` should not be null given that table definition and insert statement. It should be automatically assigned a value. Sure your actual table doesn't have `INT` instead of `INTEGER` or something?

Comment: It is definitely INTEGER

Answer (score 2):

Because of some strange defaults in SQLite, it does this automatically.  You can see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=a8021197f694ad8e105c7fca327eecb2).

What is happening is that all tables have a `rowid` column that is auto-incremented.  An integer primary key is automatically a synonym for `rowid`, so it gets incremented.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Don't get used to this behavior, because it is peculiar to SQLite.  You can define the column as `autoincrement`, although that adds a tad of overhead.

Comment: omg i did it and it said `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`

Comment: @Newbie101 . . . The dbfiddle?  It is working fine for me.  But you can test this on your database.

Answer (score 1):

just add `AUTOINCREMENT` besides the definition of the column within the `CREATE TABLE` statement as

> `PenguinID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=fdf1acaf6d39feef27117143e5726a4c)</kbd>

Comment: Just make sure to [read the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and make an informed decision about if you actually *need* `AUTOINCREMENT` - you usually don't.